# Video for motion tracking is missing

Tags: video, tracking

I was motion tracking a scene, after I clicked on setup tracking scene, I went to my previous saved file, which was before I clicked and on setup tracking scene, but when I came back my scene was gone, but markers remained.. and I could still play the video, but no image was showing. Also, you can see at the bottom that the video is here "scene 16-.mp4", but dunno it just disappeared.

Do you guys know what happened, or how it could be fixed?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is the clip in the same folder in your computer? Have you tried Clip>Reload Clip? Are you in a frame number that exists on the clip? Did you change any of the Start Frame of Frame Offset values in "Footage Information"?